# How could I use rxjs debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged with angular input events (e.g., click or input)

Tags: angular8, rxjs6

How could I use rxjs `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged` with angular input events `(input)` or `(click)`

I can't use `fromEvent` because I also need to pass parameter (Example below)

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items>
 <input [(ngModel)]="item.name" (input)="inputChanged(item.id)">
</li>
```

So I went with `Subject` (Example below)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." (input)="inputFn($event, 'myParam')"  #myInput>

@ViewChild("myInput", { static: true }) myInput;
private inputEvent = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {
    this.inputEvent
      .pipe(
        // map((obj: any) => obj.evt.target.value),
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("res", res.evt.target.value);
      });
  }

  inputFn(evt, param) {
    this.inputEvent.next({evt, param});
  }
```

In the above example, there is no use of `distinctUntilChanged()`. If I filter with map `map((obj: any) => obj.evt.target.value)` and look for value change (distinct) I am going to get only input value not parameter.

My requirement is - I want to wait until user finished entering text and also if user re-enter want to check if value is not same as previous and also want to get parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use in `distinctUntilChanged` operator the `compare function`

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("myInput", { static: true }) myInput;
  private inputEvent = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputEvent
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged((previous: any, current: any) => previous.value === current.value)
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("res", res.evt.target.value);
      });
  }

  inputFn(evt, param) {
    this.inputEvent.next({evt, param, value: evt.target.value});
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8nq1b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It works for the first time only, If you enter any new text after previous one then no console log has been printed :(

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz, now it works fine. It worked only the first time because in the distinctUntilChanged the condition on the event.target.value was a fail, "previous" and the "current" have the same reference to the HTML input because it is an object and in consequence, have the same value in the condition. So I added property value in the object to get a primitive and now the operator can compare a real previous value and a real current value.